# Loop ogg file in html audio embed

Tags: html, loops, audio

So I need to loop an audio file on my site, However I can only get it to play once even if using `loop=true`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

    <embed height="0px" width="0px" src="music.ogg" loop="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `<embed>` which could end up using most any audio player registered on the system.  These players don't really have standard attributes that they use.

Consider using HTML5 audio instead:

```
<audio src="music.ogg" loop />
```

Comment: When I replace my code with that my html underneath it all goes away and no audio plays :/

Comment: @BattleDash Yeah, well, perhaps fix your invalid HTML problem!  Use the W3C validator, or your browser's developer tools to figure it out.